# Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I installed tomcat 8.5.5 But it showing **shutdown.sh failure**. Here my tomcat.service file and it showing problem...

List item

> [Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
>   After=network.target
>
> [Service] Type=forking
>
> Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm//usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386/jre
>   Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
>   Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
>   Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
>   Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
>
> ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
>   ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
>
> User=tomcat Group=tomcat UMask=0007 RestartSec=10 Restart=always
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: Do you have anything which is logged in catalina.out?

Comment: I use this formula and i am new of it. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Can you navigate to path opt/tomcat/logs, and see if there are is any catalina.out file ?